# Space in Java command-line arguments throwing error in Amazon cloud

Tags: java, shell, amazon-ec2, command-line, executable-jar

I'm running following command in Amazon cloud(server ec2 platform Linux ) but the terminal is throwing an error.

```
java -jar runnable.jar getinfo -n "kaus mond"
```

> ERROR: Was passed main parameter 'mond"' but no main parameter was
>   defined.

But the same command in my local windows system is working fine.
If there is no space in "kaus mond" then working fine in Amazon cloud as well but with space not accepting.
Please suggest me how to make it work with white space.

Answer (score 1):

Use single instead of double quotes around the string parameter:

`java -jar runnable.jar getinfo -n 'kaus mond'`